# В RichEdit не работает кнопка delete

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. У меня странная проблемка в RichEdit не работает кнопка delete удалить и вставить заново пробовал.
Дайте совет...

Comment: У меня Delete в RichEdit работает и работала (в режиме RunTime) всегда, может Delphi очень левая. Что-то мне не очень понятен Ваш вопрос - поподробней как-нибудь. На всякий случай, попробуйте переставить среду - может что в процессе установки дало сбой. Естественно, я могу лишь угадывать!..

Answer (score 1):

**Read only** посмотри, если *True* то измени на *False*

Comment: Это поможет лишь в том случае, когда ни один символ в RichEdit нельзя ввести.